# How to generate more than 2 views on one single url?

Tags: python, django

Please, help to understand if it is possible to do this.
There is an index page where should be placed contact form django-contact-form.readthedocs.org

Code views.py in index:

```
def index(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('index.html', args)
```

Code views.py in contact_form:

```
class ContactFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ContactForm
    template_name = 'contact_form/contact_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return super(ContactFormView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ContactFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
        return kwargs

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('contact_form_sent')
```

Separetly, this works perfect. For example, we have got "example.com/" and contact form works on "example.com/contact_form"
It is possible to make it work on "example.com/" ?

Comment: Yes, you can by changing the relevant line in your `urls.py`. Can you post it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a form to be embedded through all of your pages, normally you would add the form through a [context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors), then delegate the form submit action via the [action attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) to the appropriate view. To keep your users on the page they where at, you can add a hidden form element, e.g. "next" and use the `FormView.get_success_url` method to redirect back to the former view.

By default form views use the reserved 'form' variable, so you might want to use a different variable name to avoid collision.

Here's a start

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns += urlpatterns('',
    url('^handle_form/$', MyFormView.as_view(), name="handle_form"),
)
```

**views.py**

```
class MyFormView(FormView):
    # other stuff

    def get_success_url(self):
        # get the variable from request.GET.get('next')
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(some_view)
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="{% url "handle_form" %}">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url "...current_page..." %}" />
    <!-- other stuff -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it easily by using conditional statement over request method type. Take a look here -

in your view.py:

```
from django.template import RequestContext, loader

def index(request):
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    template = loader.get_template('template.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'form_class': ContactForm,
        'args':args,
        'success_url': '/',
    })
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```